# Extjs 4 gauge chart, how to change the maximum limit value dynamically?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I have the following gauge chart, the store is loaded from xml file.

```
var gaugechart = Ext.create('Ext.chart.Chart', {
        xtype: 'chart',
        width: 600,
        height: 200,
        insetPadding: 20,
        flex: 1,
        renderTo: 'gaugeDiv',
        store: store,
        axes: [{
            type: 'gauge',
            position: 'gauge',
            minimum: 0,
            maximum: 100,
            steps: 10,
            margin: 7
        }],
```

the maximum value is 100, but I want to use a maximum value from the value in the store.
Note: in the store there is actual and max value such as
[{actually:5},{max:10}]

I want a gauge using these value. How can I change this max value?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `gaugechart.axes` to enumerate and set `minimum` and `maximum` values for any axis.